# How to render a field collection?

Tags: entities, theming, commerce

How can I properly render a field collection ? Is there any specific function for that ? I tried `field_view_field` but it does not output *children fields*.

My field collection is attached to a *line item entity*, and I want to display it in a *Commerce checkout pane review*.

```
function mymodule_pane_review($form, $form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  //loading line item
  $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($order->commerce_line_items['und'][0]['line_item_id']);
  //loading field_collection from its id
  $paxsup = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($line_item->field_paxsup['und'][0]['value']));

  return drupal_render(field_attach_view('field_collection_item',$paxsup, 'full'));
}
```

but get an error *EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type field_collection_item*

**EDIT :** I got a step forward, with the use either of

```
$paxsups = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($line_item->field_paxsup['und'][0]['value']));
$paxsup = end($paxsups);
//or shortcut, as per Marcvangend
$paxsup = field_collection_field_get_entity($line_item->field_paxsup['und'][0]);
```

`dsm($paxsup)` now returns

[image: dsm($paxsup)]

So I can output a child field with

```
$view = field_view_field('field_collection_item', $paxsup, 'field_paxsup_civilite', $display);
return drupal_render($view);
```

**EDIT 2:** I ended chaining #markup

```
$display = array('label' => 'hidden');
$cv = field_view_field('field_collection_item', $paxsup, 'field_paxsup_civilite', $display);
$nom = field_view_field('field_collection_item', $paxsup, 'field_paxsup_nom', $display);
$prenom = field_view_field('field_collection_item', $paxsup, 'field_paxsup_prenom', $display);
$date = field_view_field('field_collection_item', $paxsup, 'field_paxsup_datenaiss', $display);
$view .= $cv[0]['#markup'] .' '. $nom[0]['#markup'] .' '. $prenom[0]['#markup'] .t(', né(e) le '). $date[0]['#markup'] ;
```

But I'm not happy with this "old style" solution, would have preferred to find a more elegant and Drupal way to output that field collection

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look how the field_collection module itself renders field collections in the [field_collection_field_formatter_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!field_collection!field_collection.module/function/field_collection_field_formatter_view/7) function. I think it's important to note that is uses field_collection_field_get_entity() to load a field collection.

Looking at the code (not tested) I think you can do something like this:

```
if ($field_collection = field_collection_field_get_entity($line_item->field_paxsup['und'][0])) {
  return $field_collection->view('full');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! Out of the box, your snippet returns `field_collection_item: ` ? Not sure I understand how you suggest to use it.

Comment: OK, I don't know what the rest of your code does so that's hard to debug for me. You could try `return drupal_render($field_collection->view('full'));` instead. Also, make sure the full view mode of the field collection is configured correctly.

Comment: Of course you can't do the job for me ;) I edited the question with my progress. `field_collection_field_get_entity` is a kind of shortcut that gives me the full FieldCollectionItemEntity, but I still feel stupid on how to render all children fields

Comment: I think it better to not go into the field collection and take specific field out of it, but rather navigate to /admin/structure/field-collections and click the 'manage display' link for your field collection. That page should allow you to configure the visibility, formatter and order of the fields in your field collection. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not really, sorry : as you can see in `dpm($fieldcollection)`, there's no *view* property in FieldCollectionItemEntity object. So `$field_collection->view('full')` or similar fails. I already went several times to related manage display page and tried all possibilities :(( At the moment I ended chaining `#markup` of each `field_view_field` child array, which is a horrible solution

Comment: Sorry it isn't working for you. I would need a full installation and a debugger to understand what's going on. In any case, be aware that dpm() does have some limitations. While it can show public properties of objects, I don't think it will list `view()` (which is a *method* not a property). This [documentation](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21field_collection%21field_collection.module/class/FieldCollectionItemEntity/7) says that the FieldCollectionItemEntity should have a view() method since it extends the Entity class.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the above answer if you put the below into a node preprocess it should work

```
function MODULETHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // ...
  foreach ($variables['field_conference_day'] as $day) {
    if ($field_collection = field_collection_field_get_entity($day)) {
      $conference_days[] = drupal_render($field_collection->view('full'));
    }
  }
  $variables['conference_days'] = $conference_days;
  // ...
}
```

You can then render `$conference_days` in your theme node template file.

Note that `field_collection_field_get_entity` wants a field item. Always good to check the source code.